# Why did qName work and LocalName did not?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I was learning the Java SAX API. I made my own XML feed using php. Here is the XML Document

[image]

Now when i wanted to make my application output to the console nothing came up. I pinpointed the problem to the `endElement` method in my `XMLHandler` that extends `DefaultHandler`. Here is my implementation of it.

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
       //I added the next three lines for debugging
        System.out.println("Found End Element " + count + " times");
        System.out.println("Localname = " + localName);
        System.out.println("QName = " + qName);
        super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        if (this.currentItem != null){
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(me.osama.XMLParsing.BaseFeedParser.ITEMNAME)){
                currentItem.setItemName(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(me.osama.XMLParsing.BaseFeedParser.ITEMSITE)){
                currentItem.setItemSite(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(me.osama.XMLParsing.BaseFeedParser.ITEMNO)){
                currentItem.setItemNo(builder.toString());
            } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(me.osama.XMLParsing.BaseFeedParser.ITEM)){
                System.out.println(currentItem);
                items.add(currentItem);
            }
            builder.setLength(0);   
        }
        count++;
    }
```

Turns out that `localName` kept on coming empty hence the conditions never held true and the code never went into the decision block. On the other hand `qName` brought all names out properly and  once i changed the variable to `qName` the `List<Item> items` collection type did fill up and worked correctly.

I am here to ask why did qName work and not localName? Whereas the tutorial from IBM's DeveloperWorks used an RSS feed and `localName` worked perfectly for him.

P.S. this is the feed the IBM Tutorial used: http://www.androidster.com/android_news.rss

Comment: The [API spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html) says that `localName` would be empty if namespace processing is not performed.

Comment: [This article](http://www.saxproject.org/namespaces.html) talks about namespace processing.

Comment: @srkavin please post this as an answer. it solves the mystery. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [SAX namespace for Java API](http://www.saxproject.org/namespaces.html),

> By default, an XML reader will report a Namespace URI and a localName
>   for every element that belongs in a namespace, in both the start and
>   end handler.

Perhaps, if you add a namespace to the XML and define your elements in that namespace, it would return a valid `localName`. The article also mentions that with namespace processing, some implementations will return *empty* `qName`.

Comment: thank you. After reading the article at http://www.saxproject.org/namespaces.html my confusion was cleared. And also learned the proper and standard way to represent XML feeds. Thank you